# Implementing a hashtable for a question/answer group

Tags: java, dictionary, hashtable

What's the easiest way to implement a hashtable (or use a better way) to store a list of questions and their associated answers (1 possible answer per question)?

Originally I had created an ArrayList to store the questions. I could have made a second ArrayList for the answers, but once I have a lot of questions, trying to match up questions and answers gets complicated.

Can someone post a quick code sample? Thanks!

Comment: Java has a `HashMap` class that does key/value associativity.

Comment: And even if you decide to use two `ArrayList`, it's still easy to match questions with answers: for each `questions.get(i)` there's an associated `answers.get(i)` (possibly `null`).

Comment: True for GETTING the matching answer to the question, but if I want to add a bunch of questions, I have to make sure to input the questions and answers in the same order, and if I want to edit question/answer pairs, that's more difficult as well.

Answer (score 4):

What would you want the key to be? If there's only one possible answer per question, and there may *not* be an answer in some cases, that sounds like an ideal reason to have an `Answer` reference within the `Question` class. Then just have a list of questions.

If that *doesn't* meet some particular requirement, please give more information about what you're trying to do. (For example, you may need to navigate from an answer to a question... in which case you *could* have a reference from the answer back to the question in the object... it's a bit messy in terms of cyclic references, and doesn't lend itself to immutable types, but it wouldn't be entirely unreasonable.)

One reason to prefer having a list of questions over a simple map is that questions *tend* to be naturally ordered in some way - whereas maps are inherently unordered, usually. But we'd need to know more about your actual context to say for sure whether or not that was relevant.

Answer (score 1):

A HashMap is a perfect choice, but I'd recommend that you go a step further.

Java's an object-oriented language.  Why not create a Questionnaire abstraction?

```
public class Questionnaire
{
    private Map<String, String> questionsAndAnswers = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // more follows.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this simple 1:1 mapping you don't necessarily need a complex HashMap. A simple class, composed of a question and it's associated answer is enough:

```
public class Question {
   final private String text;
   final private String answer;
   public Question(String text, String answer) {
     this.text= text;
     this.answer = answer;
   }

   public String getText() { return text; }
   public String getAnswer() { return answer; }
   public String toString() { return text + " - " + answer; }
}
```

Then, later in your code, you can create a list that holds all Question:

```
   List<Question> questionnaire = new ArrayList<Question>();
   questionnaire.add(new Question("1+1?", "2"));
   System.out.println("Question 1: " + questionnaire.get(0).getText());
```

Comment: You should make `text` and `answer` final if they're not going to be modified after `Question` is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic requirement is met by any class that implements the ***Map*** interface (`java.util.Map`).

However in choosing the implementation it is imperative to consider which operations you wish to optimise for:
{**Insert**, **Delete**, **Random Access**, **Sequential Access**}

If you require only random access to each question (and answer), then the **`HashMap`** is probably your best bet.

The most common use-case of a dictionary like application is listing series of entries. Thus, if you are going to be displaying series of questions (and answers) consider using a variant of `HashMap`, **`LinkedHashMap`**.

Your basic hash table functionality is provided by `HashMap`, and it will yield O(1) complexity for lookup, however iteration, required for displaying "series" or "listings" can be expensive.

In this case a **`LinkedHashMap`** would serve your needs best because it provides a linked list tacked on to the underlying hashtable; therefore iteration or **sequential access** becomes *inexpensive*. However, the tradeoff of this is that this makes addition and deletion of new entries (questions) more expensive.